# How to get below linked list with friend operator to working?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to execute linked list with the below code.But I am unable to figure out the mistake in it.
I got the concept of it but I am failing to implement the same.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 struct Node {
 int data;
 Node *next;
 Node(int j) : data(j), next(nullptr) {}
 friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Node &n) {
 cout << "Node\n"
     << "\tdata: " << n.data << "\n";
    return os;
  }
 };
void addElement(Node **head, int data){
Node *temp = nullptr;
temp->data = data;
temp->next=nullptr;
Node *cur = *head;
while(cur) {
    if(cur->next == nullptr) {
        cur->next = temp;
        return;
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}
 };
 void printList(const Node *head){
 const Node *list = head;
while(list) {
    cout << list;
    list = list->next;
}
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
  };
 void deleteList(Node *head){
Node *delNode =nullptr;
while(head) {
    delNode = head;
    head = delNode->next;
    delete delNode;
}};

  int main() {
  Node *list = nullptr;
  addElement(&list, 1);
  addElement(&list, 2);
  printList(list);
   deleteList(list);
   return 0;
   }
```

after compiling I am getting no error and no output.So I am unable to figure what is going wrong or else my implementation of which is not right!

Comment: What "mistake" are you referring to?

Comment: code is not working in total

Comment: Where does it get stuck? Try a debugger, or put print statements between each call to your list? i.e. Do the two `addElement` calls work? Does it get stuck in the `print` function? Does it hang, or return with nothing printed?

Comment: @pptOUT _"code working exactly in total"_ That you don't have any compilation errors, doesn't mean your code _"works"_.

Comment: Sorry but I am using online compiler so I was unable to get exact location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an error straightaway

```
void addElement(Node **head, int data){
Node *temp = nullptr;
temp->data = data;
```

`temp` is null, but you dereference it. It's an error to dereference a null pointer.

I guess you meant this

```
void addElement(Node **head, int data) {
    Node *temp = new Node(data);
```

which allocates a new `Node`, initialises it with `data` and makes `temp` point to the newly allocated `Node`.

Comment: so this eliminates the usage of temp->data =data ?

Comment: @pptOUT Yes because that step is done in the `Node` constructor.

Comment: I have updated with your answer but I couldnt see any output may be my print statement is also not right!Could you please help me with my print statement also

Comment: @pptOUT It's not the print routine that's wrong. The problem is that (even with my correction) there's nothing in the `addElement` routine that changes the value of `*head`. So `list` in main remains null, and the print routine prints nothing.

Comment: so any changes to make in addElement func

Comment: Actually the print routine is wrong as well `cout << list;` should be `cout << *list;`.

Comment: I'll leave you to fix the `addElement` routine. You need to test for the empty list as a special case, and set `*head` to `temp` if it is, otherwise add `temp` to the end of the existing list as you are doing now.